# python question (I know no python!)

Tags: python, scripting

I'm getting my head around Blender after finally giving up on Lightwave!...
I have zero knowledge of Python either.

I found a nice script for setting every object in a scene to not render (trying to set up for a shadows only pass - thanks to someone for that one!).
My question is: is it possible to switch off 'use nodes' (materials) for every selected object in a scene in a similar way?
I'm trying to save myself 10 seconds odd a frame loading up textures that are not being rendered basically... But with a shit-load of objects I'd rather not switch off nodes manually for each object.

Whilst I'm asking: is there any way to do a true 'shadows only' render?
All shadow catcher (ground basically) shadows, and all shadows on all objects as well.
Or maybe 2 passes with just shadows, one for the shadow catcher / ground, and another for all object caught shadows?

Cheers!
Mark

Comment: have you checked the shadow pass in the render layers panel?

Comment: Have done & it works as it works (OK but a bit wierd with transparency that is), my question is how do I turn off materials in all objects at once? As in- un-check the 'use nodes' box for every material in the scene without doing it one at a time manually? The other question is how do I generate a shadows-only render? Cheers, Mark.

Comment: Samir, forget my first comment: misread your suggestion! Tried the shadow pass: works nicely if you're using a blender light to light the scene, looks nothing like correct if using an HDRI environment map to light the scene (as I am). Cheers, Mark

Comment: Samir, just tried the shadow pass in Blender 2.8; it's still stuffed if you're using an environment HDRI as lighting- looks nothing like the shadow pass if you use a Sun lamp... Cheers, Mark

Comment: How about the shadow catcher? in 2.8 you could put the objects you want to hide into a new collection then set the view layer to exclude. that should work with an environment texture.

Comment: I'm using shadow catcher already, with the script that turns off the camera visibility checkbox for everything- then I just strn it back on for the ground object. I tried 2.8 last night (as it renders way quicker than 2.9b), but sort of came across a showstopper with Alpha 2- https://developer.blender.org/T57668 So I'm still looking for the elusive shadow pass, with an environment map lighting scheme, and all the shadows, not just the ground (as in shadow catcher objects do not self-shadow, they only cast onto other objects)...